# Is there a way to extract data from javascripted websites that are not accessed by RSelenium using R?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, webdriver, rselenium

I am still new to the community and would really appreciate your help.
I am trying to extract data from this website http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/302427/302442/gljdhcd/index.html
What I want to do is to get the table. However, whenever I try to access the website using RSelenium, I cannot open the website. Is it related to my computer or is it something on the website that blocks me from accessing it? Here is the code that I used

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

firefox_binary_path <- "C:/Users/lokij/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"

firefox_capabilities <- list(
  "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
    "binary" = firefox_binary_path
  )
)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", chromever = NULL, extraCapabilities = firefox_capabilities)

rDC <- rD$client

rDC$open()

rDC$navigate("http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/302427/302442/gljdhcd/index.html")

element <- rDC$findElement("css", "k-pager-info k-label")

element_text <- element$getElementText()

rDC$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

Here, I have tried starting a webdriver session to navigate the webpage. However, the webpage does not open in this way. This is a way that I tried before on other websites and it worked on similar pages. Can you help me in finding another way to access?

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that I could not open the website in another search engine while the session was open but I dont know if that is because of my connection or the webdriver session.